# IntelliJ Making Dirty Files in Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a weird problem. Randomly, IntelliJ seems to be "modifying" some of my runConfigurations with bogus changes.

Git Diff:

```
modified: .idea/runConfigurations/Build_and_Deploy.xml
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
@ Build_and_Deploy.xml:15 @
      <option name="Make" enabled="false" />
    </method>
  </configuration>
-</component>
+</component>
```

Looks like it removed `</component>` and then re-added it? I just don't understand why the file is dirty in git now, and why that would have happened.

Anyone have any idea?

This happens on a larger basis as well with other things. Like this bogus change:

```
-    <option name="SCRIPT_NAME" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/src/main/build/remote/build.sh" />
+    <option name="SCRIPT_NAME" value="$PROJECT_DIR$$PROJECT_DIR$/../main/build/remote/build.sh" />
```

Comment: If your original file had whitespace other than a single newline character after the closing element, that original file was wrong, and the new version is right. The paste into SO doesn't have byte-for-byte accuracy, unfortunately, so we can't distinguish this from what you've given here.

Comment: Interesting. CharlesDuffy, how can I proactively test my XML runConfigurations for these types of issues? What is the standard against which IntelliJ is trying to align these files to?

Comment: `xmlstarlet val` or `xmllint` will both detect well-formedness issues. That said, I don't actually know offhand if trailing *whitespace* will make a document officially malformed, or is merely bad practice. (Trailing non-whitespace bytes, OTOH, definitely make a document malformed).

Comment: (BTW, if IntelliJ wanted to do the official Right Thing, they'd comply with [xml-c14n](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) as a standard for expressing XML documents in a canonical way to avoid spurious changes; that said, I don't know if they do or don't attempt same).

Comment: Yeah that's the trouble. `xmllint` says that everything is fine. Weird.

Comment: Actually, there *is* an easy thing you can do: Try running both the original version and the new one through `xmlstarlet c14n`, and see which one it changes. (If it changes both, then we know they don't try to comply with the standard; *sigh*).

Comment: Ok I'll try that. But this is also part of a larger issue I believe. See the example I just added to the end of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is similar issue reported for IntelliJ, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91607

Answer (score 1):

Seems it adds/changes/removes end-of-line character.

Comment: If this is the case there will be a `\ No newline at end of file` after either the `-` or the `+` line in `git diff` output. Presumably it's other whitespace, *not* the newline (or it was a tool other than `git diff` that generated the output given in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a whitespace issue. If you open the XML file in IntelliJ, the left hand side will be color coded for different kinds of changes. By default, these are:

- Green for additions
- Grey for deletions
- Blue for changes
- Brown for whitespace-only changes

If you see a brown margin on the left, then the line only differs by whitespace.